# How to IF or ELSE echo user IP and loading speed

Tags: php, html, web, ip, ip-address

I noticed today when loading test page getting user IP the page load slow compared when without it. Can that be possible or it is my internet having interferences?

Also I cannot make the following code to work I don't know where the problem is:

```
<?php if ($privilege!= 'ADMIN'){echo 
"REG IP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
exit();
} 
?>
```

How does I must write this kind of echo?

Comment: That's highly unlikely. The value already exists in the `$_SESSION` array, so any difference in performance by accessing it is only going to be in the order of microseconds at most. What are your benchmarking results?

Comment: The `$_SERVER` superglobal should be populated before your script is even executed, so I would say no.

Comment: as a side note, where is privilege defined?

Comment: privilege is populated before this code comparing current session name and user in database but in this example I am using only this to test speed and took 3 secs to load. It must be my internet connection. Thanks guys

Comment: If you're going to do load/speed testing, probably best to use a third party like [blitz.io](http://blitz.io) to eliminate factors such as your internet connection/computer capabilities

Comment: scrowler why are you recommending payed services? It cost 30usd month to test it

Comment: How to correctly write this code?   echo " . '$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']' . "

Comment: @quieroprivacidad You may want to start with a very basic PHP tutorial if you're asking that.

Comment: I edited the question sorry I was missing 2 lines of code

Comment: <?php if ($privilege!= 'ADMIN'){echo 
"REG IP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
exit();
} 
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's IP is always part of the request - outputting it won't make anything take longer.

A simple:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

will output the remote user's IP address (as long as it's in a PHP block).

Comment: Sorry I edited the question with correct code I was missing 2 lines of code

Comment: @quieroprivacidad In your edit, `echo 
"REG IP {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";` or `echo 
"REG IP " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: Wow it worked thanks a lot so the problem was the { and } missing. I will mark the question as correct

Answer (score 0):

Missing "

Better you do it like this:

```
echo "REG IP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
```

or concat the string and the variable:

```
echo 'REG IP ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```